# Import word-wrapped text file in Python

Tags: pandas, text, import, text-files, word-wrap

I have a .txt file and need to import into Python and add columns.

Currently my data in the text file is as follows:
55590003210030003399210310003310210210210204000000000000000000
000000000136.67JE/ FH Cord 2/2 DAILY FL
21021000000000000000000044000601
55590003210030003399210310003310210210210204000000000000000000
000000000500.67JE/ FH Cord 2/4 DAILY FL
21021000000000000000000044000601

As you can see the two rows are word wrapped - I need to import this and create multiple columns.

```
#My Code:
data = pd.read_csv('LAST.txt_02_03_2021_10_60', header=None)
data.columns = ['BK_NO', 'Acct', 'CST', 'XDATE', 'D_C', 'AMOUNT', 'DESC', 'PXDATE', 
'DATE']
```

#This is how the text string should be extracted for the columns

BK_NO = The first 3 numbers [0:3]  #555

Acct = [05:13]  #000321003

CST = [17:20]  #3399

XDATE = [33:38]  #210210

D_C = [21:22]  #21

AMOUNT = \n [0:15]  #000000000136.67  - (this is extracted from the second line)

DESC = \n [16:38]  #JE/ FH Cord 2/2 DAILY FL  - (this is extracted from the second line)

PXDATE = \n [0:5] #210210 - (this is extracted from the third line)

DATE = #this field will be blank

My data should look like this:

| bk_no | Acct | CST | XDATE | D_C | AMOUNT | DESC | PXDATE | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 154 | 000321003 | 3399 | 02/10/2021 | 21 | 136.67 | JE/ FH Cord 2/2 DAILY FL | 02/10/2021 |  |

Is this possible? Can anyone help?

thanks

Comment: do you have anything to define a record limiter? clearly i's not newline (\n).  is it a fixed number of characters.  it appears you have a fixed width format which also includes new lines.  hence I would expect using a buffer to read and pandas `read_fwf()` to form a solution

Comment: Thank you - your answer at least pointed me in the right direction.  I was able to resolve using pd.read_fwf and using colspecs to get the desired result.